# How can I calculate dotproduct for uint8_t array using Eigen library?

Tags: c++, eigen, dot-product

I would like to calculate the dotproduct for two uint8 type array in C/C++, naive implemented as:

```cpp
uint64_t dotproduct_u8_naive(uint8_t* a, uint8_t* b, uint32_t len)
{
    uint64_t res = 0;
    for(uint32_t i=0; i<len; i++) {
        res += a[i] * b[i];
    }
    return res;
}
```

Since Eigen library is declared as being with SIMD for fast speed, I'd like to passing two raw C array, then assign to Eigen's type, then calculate dotproduct result. Implemented as this:

```cpp
uint64_t dotproduct_u8_eigen(uint8_t* a, uint8_t* b, uint32_t len)
{
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<uint8_t, 1, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>> va(a, len);
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<uint8_t, 1, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>> vb(b, len);
    uint64_t res = va.dot(vb);
    return res;
}
```

The array `a` and `b` 's elements are none-zero, however, **`dotproduct_u8_eigen` always returns zero, which is different with exepected result from `dotproduct_u8_naive()`**. This seems strange to me, since I've implemented float32 type vector dotproduct in the same way and get correct result:

```cpp
float dotproduct_f32_eigen(float* a, float* b, uint32_t len) {
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>> va(a, len);
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>> vb(b, len);
    float res = va.dot(vb);
    return res;
}
```

My question is: is `dotproduct_u8_eigen()` wrong? How can I modify `dotproduct_u8_eigen()` to get correct result?

---

I can get correct result by convert u8 matrix to uint64 matrix like the following, which is, much slower than naive implementation:

```
uint64_t dotproduct_u8_eigen(uint8_t* a, uint8_t* b, uint32_t len)
{
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<uint8_t, 1, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>> va(a, len);
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<uint8_t, 1, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>> vb(b, len);
    
    Eigen::Matrix<uint64_t, 1, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> fa = va.cast<uint64_t>();
    Eigen::Matrix<uint64_t, 1, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> fb = vb.cast<uint64_t>();

    return fa.dot(fb);
}
```

Comment: What is the return type of product of two vectors of `uint8_t`? If it is `uint8_t` then there is no way it is gonna work. Furthermore, compiler should be quite capable to vectoring that simple product. It wouldn't vectorize a dot product of floats/doubles as it is depends on the order of operations.

Comment: @ALX23z I think the return type of product of two vectors of `uint8_t` should be `uint64_t`. Maybe this is not correct; However, tried to just cout result, ignore explicit declare return type, i.e. `std::cout << va.dot(vb) << std::endl`, still not same result as naive implementation.

Comment: The question is not what it should be - the question is what is the return type. You can test what type is returned.

Comment: Try `uint64_t res = va.cast<uint64_t>().dot(vb.cast<uint64_t>());` This probably still won't be as efficient as the native loop, but should be much faster than your last alternative. Generally, Eigen is not very efficient with mixed-type expressions, yet.

Comment: @chtz Thanks for providing this alternative. Tested on my Android ARMv8 phone, time cost is nearly same as naive implementation (element-wise), which is nearly 20x faster than my last alternative.